# Script to Enable RMA Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, magento2.3.2, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.2-p1

I want to enable RMA for all products in one go. How can I obtain that? Please specify.

Thanks,
Rashi

Comment: Hello, you can use adobe commerce (EE version), or look for a module that do this

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: Run a custom script to iterate all product collection into a loop and change values programmatically or find the responsible table for storing is_returnable column for products and run manual query in DB to change all product's is_returnable value

Comment: You can try to find something free on github like this https://github.com/KrishaWeb/magento2-rma but oi need to be sure if this work without any issue

Comment: Thanks, @NathaOdedara. Let me try this DB approach

Comment: Thanks, @MohamedElMrabet. Let me check & confirm